# the flask request located in wrong url?

Tags: python, flask

In my app.py the url part like this:

```
    @app.route('/admin', methods=['GET','POST'])
def tiger_admin():
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #print 'POST'
        ...
        return render_template('admin.html', blogs=blogs)
    else:
        pass
    return render_template('admin.html', blogs=blogs)
```

another one:

```
@app.route('/edit/<blogid>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def editblog(blogid):
    print 'processing...'
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'posting...'
        ...
        return render_template('edit_status.html',status)
    return render_template('edit.html', blog=blog)
```

Now in template 'admin.html' like this:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('editblog',blogid=blog.id) }}">change{{blog.id}}</a>
```

then if we click the `<a>`, it will return 'edit.html' like this:

```
...    
<dd><input type="submit" value="update">
...
```

but when I click the button 'update', the flask processes it with 'POST' in 'tiger_admin', which should be 'editblog'
How could I find where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Your `<input>` element is inside some `<form>` element. The `action` attribute of that `<form>` element is incorrect.

> How could I find where the problem is?

You can start by examining the `<form>` element in browser. From there, look for the corresponding `<form>` element in the template.